# How to add back '"Microsoft Foundation Classes for C++' in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have installed Visual Studio 2013 on my desktop. But when I install it, I don't have 'Microsoft Foundation Classes for C++' checked when I installed.  How can I add that library/functionalities back without uninstall VS and re-install it again?

Thank you.

Comment: You should just be able to launch the installer and selection that option.

Comment: May be try with repair hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These exact instructions are Windows 7-centric, but basically hold true for all versions of windows.

1. Go to Windows' Control Panel -> Add/Remove Programs.
2. Located Visual Studio's entry and highlight it.
3. Click "Change".
4. Once the VS setup opens, choose "Modify".

[image]

5. Check-mark "Microsoft Foundation Classes for C++", and/or whichever other features you'd like to add or remove.
6. Click "Update" and follow the prompts to complete the setup wizard.